# Firebase .limitToFirst() is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to limit the number of data i return from firebase, currently its bringing back everything which obviously isn't good.

Is it possible to bring back the latest 10 rows? I was looking at limitToFirst(limit), but couldn't quite get the syntax working in my code. Any help? thanks

Current working code:

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/");
      $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
        var u = $('#nameIpt').val();
        var m = $('#msgIpt').val();
        myDataRef.push({name: u, text: m});
        $('#msgIpt').val('');
      });

      myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        var msg = snapshot.val();
        displayMsg(msg.name, msg.text);
      });
```

I tried the following

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/");
      $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
        var u = $('#nameIpt').val();
        var m = $('#msgIpt').val();
        myDataRef.push({name: u, text: m});
        $('#msgIpt').val('');
      });
      myDataRef.limitToFirst(10).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        var msg = snapshot.val();
        displayMsg(msg.name, msg.text);
      });
```

Comment: Your current code doesn't use `limitToFirst`. Can you show what you tried?

Comment: updated with what i tried

Comment: Any message within the console? Based on https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data, you should to use limitToLast instead

Comment: What's the problem with the latest code you shared? I do **highly** recommend that you update to a more recent version of Firebase (see https://firebase.google.com/docs). But the syntax for this hasn't changed as far as I recall. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/orderbykey.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing either `orderByChild()`, `orderByValue()`, `orderByKey()` or `orderByPriority()` here.

You need to add either on of them before you use `endAt()`, `startAt()`, `equalTo()`, `isEqual()`, `limitToFirst()` and `limitToLast()`.

**Example:**

```
myDataRef.orderByChild(refChild).limitToFirst(10).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var msg = snapshot.val();
    displayMsg(msg.name, msg.text);
});
```

Comment: Hi, it says myDataRef.orderByKey is not a function

Comment: What do you mean by that? Try other order, orderByChild() instead.

Comment: Thanks for replying. in the console thats the error message i get. same for the edited answer

Comment: Can you include your JSON data structure in the question? Considering so many possibilities.

Comment: How else can you do it?